# Renaming a React Native project?

Tags: react-native

Are there instructions for what needs to be changed in order to rename a React Native project? I have an app called something along the lines of MyAppIOS and I want to rename it to simply MyApp (now that Android support is out)

Answer (score 73, accepted):

The way I did this for android (hacky, but it works) is just changed the string app_name field in

`android/app/src/main/res/values/strings.xml`

It will change the name of your installed android app to whatever you put as the value.

Comment: Most should pick up on this but just FYI this answer is for _ANDROID ONLY_.

Comment: for both iOS and Android follow this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68641035/6363952

Comment: This actually changes the display name not the name of the project. BTW for ios, to change the display name, goto info.plist file and change the value of CFBundleDisplayName key to your desired value.

Answer (score 92):

You can change the name attribute in `package.json`, run `react-native upgrade`, and just let react overwrite the android/ios files. Don't overwrite your index files if there is unsaved code, however.

Then change your Appregistry line from

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyAppIOS', () => MyAppIOS);
```

To:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Comment: I also had to rename the main class correspondingly: class MyApp extends Component { .... etc.

Comment: this doesn't delete the old MyAppIOS files, so you'll also want to do:

```$ rm -rf android/app/src/main/java/com/myappios && rm -rf ios/MyAppIOS*```

Comment: I think that `react-native upgrade` will upgrade your react-native too, be careful because this could broken something with your dependencies.

Comment: We found a number of additional steps scattered around the web - posted a complete list (and accepting pull requests!) at: https://github.com/2MR/renaming-a-react-native-project

Answer (score 44):

What simply works for me several times is instructed below;

- First copy the directory which your to-be-name-changed application
  exists. And go to your newly cloned directory.
- Change the name at `index.ios/android.js` file which is given as a parameter to `AppRegistry`.
- Change the name and version accordingly on `package.json`
- delete `/ios` and `/android` folders which are remaining from your older app as well as the `app.json` file if you have.
- run `$react-native upgrade` to generate `/ios` and `/android` folders again.
- run `$react-native link` for any external dependency.
- finally run `$react-native run-ios` or anything you want.

Comment: Newer versions of react native have you also change the values in app.json if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes, it seems that after 0.41 react-native offer an official way to re-generate native folders `/ios` and `/android`. For more one could check [`react-native eject`](https://gist.github.com/ndejesus1227/0eb673452c34e085b3f04fd5c1cbcc9f)

Comment: Good source: https://medium.com/the-react-native-log/how-to-rename-a-react-native-app-dafd92161c35

Comment: `react-native upgrade` will actually upgrade your react-native version as well. keep that thing in mind

Answer (score 27):

For iOS, the way to change xcodeproj settings is also available.

Show <your app name> -> Info.plist and add **Bundle display name**.

changing iOS app name:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

I am probably a bit late, but for the people looking for a solid solution, there is a [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename) npm package which can do the magic.

Comment: Do not use this package. See the many other warning comments in this thread.

Answer (score 8):

1. Update displayName in app.json to the new name
2. Delete ios/ and android/ directories in root project
3. At command line Run:

   ```
   react-native eject
   react-native link
   ```

Comment: This is an expo-specific answer. It doesn't apply to standard CRNA or `react-native init` workflows.

Answer (score 8):

1. For IOS app, change in xcodeproj settings is also available.

Open `Info.plist` file from your project `directory/ios/{appname}` directory and change Bundle display name.

```
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>NEW APP NAME</string>
```

2. For android app, you can change in android folder of your project directory.

   `cd android/app/src/main/res/values/`

open `strings.xml` file and change you app name in

```
 <string name="app_name">NEW APP NAME</string>
```

Answer (score 5):

As mentioned here (https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4227), you don't need to add a `Bundle display name` key, as said by @janus_wel.

You can simply update `Bundle name` from `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` to `My App`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me. I added a build setting called CUSTOM_DISPLAY_NAME (to support different app names for debug and release), then simply updated `Bundle name` to be `$(CUSTOM_DISPLAY_NAME)`

Answer (score 5):

You might also want to check out npm package ([react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)):

> Usage:
>
> react-native-rename < newName >

It works fine for my project.

Comment: In my app, this command deletes my java files under android/app/src/main/java/com/appname!

Comment: WARNING: Do not use this library. it will ruine your project. Never use this.

Answer (score 5):

Rename react-native app with just one command [react-native-rename](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename)

Installation

`yarn global add react-native-rename`
or
`npm install react-native-rename -g`

Usage run the below command in the project's directory.

`react-native-rename <newName>`

Example:

`react-native-rename "Travel App"`

Answer (score 1):

In-Case None of solution worked for you or trying something broke your app. This is going to basics.

1. Init a new react-native project with whatever name you want to change your app to.
2. Copy Dependency list from your previous project to new one's package.json
3. Copy old project files, make sure of keeping the same structure.
4. Run `npm install`
5. Run `react-native run-android`

This should get you back on track

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vs code, then it is much easier and works really fine.

1)Open your project in vs code, goto search tab.There are two text inputs, first takes the input which you want to search in all the files in your project (some files and directories are excluded and you can manage them in settings, but that is not needed). The other text input takes the input with which you want to replace the first input in all the files (in simple words, change all occurences).

2. In the first input field, search for `com.<your_package_name>`. This is the older name of your project (current name of project which you want to change).
3. In the second input field, enter `com.<new_package_name>` and press the replace button (small icon button on the right side of 2nd input field). It will replace all the occurences of the older package name thus renaming the project.

{Repeat the above two steps with <your_package_name> only too}

4. Now goto `android>app>src>main>java>com>older_package_name` .Rename the `older_package_name` to the new package name and you are done.
5. `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..`.
6. And you are done. Run `npx react-native run-android` to test the app.

Answer (score 0):

- First of all copy the address which your want to-be-name-changed application exists. And go to your newly cloned directory.
- Replace the name at the index.ios/android.js file which is given as a parameter to AppRegistry.
- update the name and version accordingly on package.json
  remove /ios and /android folders which are remaining from your older app and from the
- run $react-native upgrade to generate /ios and /android folders again. and run $react-native link for any external dependency.
- finally, run $react-native run-ios or else.

Answer (score 0):

The following steps must be followed while renaming Project/app in react Native 
 1. create a new folder test

2. Copy and paste all files from demo to test folder
3. Change the name  in package.json file
4. Change the name  in package-lock.json file
5. Change the name in App.json file
6. Delete /ios and /android folders
7. Run react-native eject command to create /ios and /android folders again
8. run react-native link for any external dependency.
9. finally run your app by using react-native run-android command.

Form more information visit https://youtu.be/_lgH9LXf818

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way for android application is to navigate to /android/app/src/main/res/values
You will see file strings.xml

Inside the file you would see.

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">{YOUR NEW NAME}</string>
</resources>
```