# How can I regenerate ios folder in React Native project?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, react-native-ios

So a while ago I deleted the /ios directory in my react native app (let's call it X). I've been developing and testing using the android emulator but now I'd like to make sure it works on ios with xcode simulator etc.

So my current idea is to create a new react native bare project (let's call it Y) with ios folder, then follow [these steps](http://blog.tylerbuchea.com/renaming-a-react-native-project/) to rename Y so that it has the name of X and then moving the /ios directory from Y into X and trying to `run-ios`.

I'll update here how that goes, but I wondered if there is a better way and has nobody been in this situation before?

I've googled lots of things 'regenerate ios folder' 'deleted ios folder' 'add ios folder to existing..' and nothing helpful. Maybe my googlefu isn't good enough but if anyone has any suggestions, much appreciated.

Step 2 will be making sure it compiles because of dependencies and stuff but for now my goal is to just get the /ios folder back in the project and for React Native to be aware of it's existence (it has all the necessary config).

Thanks

Comment: try commands given in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/65776701/1948482
it will help you.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The process you need to follow is so similar to renaming a react native app. Basically you just need to run `react-native upgrade` in your root project directory. For further info you can check another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project). The instructions below explains how to create another react native project based on a copied one with a new name.

- First copy the directory which your to-be-name-changed application exists. And go to your newly cloned directory.
- Change the name at `index.ios/android.js` file which is given as a parameter to AppRegistry.
- Change the name and version accordingly on `package.json`
- Delete `/ios` and `/android` folders which are remaining from your older app.
- Run `$react-native upgrade` to generate `/ios` and `/android` folders again.
- Run `$react-native link` for any native dependency.
- Finally run `$react-native run-ios` or anything you want.

Comment: It's not recommended to use `react-native upgrade` anymore, it should be replaced with `react-native-git-upgrade`.

Comment: @wmcbain The reason I use `react-native upgrade` is just to re-generate `/ios` and `/android` project folders. It does not changes/updates/upgrades react native version as its name may imply. However I see that `react-native-git-upgrade` is more appropriate if you want to change the react native  version of your project.

Comment: If you have for example ios app icons inside of ios, you should not delete that folder...

Comment: Hi, I cant found the files `index.ios/android.js`. Help me to find it. Thanks

Comment: Hi, they are like [this](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/blob/master/index.android.js) and [this](https://github.com/start-react/native-starter-kit/blob/master/index.ios.js). They are fundamental for your project, if they are absent from your repo somehow you can add them manually.

Comment: react-native eject works for me instead of upgrade,..with rest steps same.

Comment: i want to generate only ios folder not android

Comment: @Yusuf If the process is still valid to produce `/ios` and `/android` folders, in the end just delete `/android` to get rid of it.

Comment: `react-native eject` was removed and does not seem to work anymore as well other options :-( creating a new project an copying files by hand seems silly for this kind of mature frameork :-(

Comment: @milkersarac `It does not changes/updates/upgrades react native version as its name may imply. ` yes it does

Answer (score 86):

Simply remove/delete android and ios (keep backup android and ios folder) and run following command:

```
  react-native eject

Supported version : 
    react-native <= 0.59.10
    react-native-cli <= 1.3.0 



   react-native upgrade --legacy true

Supported version : 
        react-native >= 0.60.0
        react-native-cli >= 2.1.0
```

Ref : [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526#issuecomment-510188117)

Edited(March 2021)

```
npm i react-native-eject
npm i @react-native-community/cli
react-native eject
```

will generate the both android and ios folder.

Ref.: [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526#issuecomment-748600715)

Comment: `react-native upgrade` (or `react-native-git-upgrade`) both didnt work for me. Simply running `react-native eject` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: `react-native eject` appears to have been removed as of React Native 0.60. My `react-native-cli` is version `2.0.1`.

Comment: `upgrade --legacy` seems to be removed too. `error: unknown option --legacy`

Comment: Looks like both of these options have been removed. Recommendation now is to init a new project and copy of the files manually. e.g. `npx react-native init YourProjectName`

Comment: The edited comment (install react-native-eject... cli... and execute eject) worked for me

Answer (score 29):

Note as of react-native 0.60.x you can use the following to regenerate ios/android directories:

```
react-native upgrade --legacy true
```

Credit here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25526

Comment: This command also worked for react-native v0.59.x with react-native-cli v2.0.0. We can specify version to keep the same react-native version: ```react-native upgrade 0.59.10 --legacy true```

Comment: this does not work on 0.61.5: `error: unknown option '--legacy'`

Answer (score 7):

Working steps **2021**.

- Delete `/ios` `/android`
- Change the app name to new name in `/app.json` and `package.json`
- Run `npx react-native upgrade` - this is important even if platform files are not generated.
- Create a separate directory and run `npx react-native init NewProjectName` there.
- Copy ios and android folders from generated project to the old project
- Run `pod install` in `/ios` in old project
- Run `cd .. && npx react-native run-ios`

Answer (score 4):

As @Alok mentioned in the comments, you can do `react-native eject` to generate the `ios` and `android` folders. But you will need an `app.json` in your project first.

```
{"name": "example", "displayName": "Example"}
```

Comment: Your approach is valid if you have created your project with CRNA. I suspect when question answered CRNA even exists. Anyway the original answer targets the projects have been created with `react-native init`. One popup question, what would you do when `ios` and `android` folders are deleted after you have already ejected your project?

Comment: @milkersarac `react-native eject` works even if the project is not created with CRNA

Answer (score 3):

It seems like `react-native eject` is no more available. The only way I could find for recreating the ios folder was to generate it from scratch.

Take a backup of your ios folder

```
mv /path_to_your_old_project/ios /path_to_your_backup_dir/ios_backup
```

Navigate to a temporary directory and create a new project with the same name as your current project

```
react-native init project_name
mv project_name/ios /path_to_your_old_project/ios
```

Install the pod dependencies inside the ios folder within your project

```
cd /path_to_your_old_project/ios
pod install
```

Comment: This is currently the correct answer according to this discussion: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275

Answer (score 3):

❯ `react-native eject`

> error Unrecognized command "eject". info Run "react-native --help" to
>   see a list of all available commands.

❯ `react-native upgrade --legacy true`

> error: unknown option `--legacy'

You can init a new project that's named the same in another folder and copy ios dir over:

inside YourProjectName directory

```
npx react-native init YourProjectName
mv YourProjectName/ios ios
rm -rf YourProjectName
```

Make sure you have clean git history before doing so, in case you need to revert

Comment: I did this but now when I npx react-native run-ios it just runs the demo "welcome to react" project instead of the existing App.js code. Am I missing a step?

Comment: @WMartin you're suppose to move the ios folder to your previous project and run the app there

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Terminal/cmd
2. Move to the folder/directory where the project **"ProjectName"** folder exist(Do not go into project directory)
3. run command as:   **react-native init "ProjectName"** and it will warn that project directory already exist but you continue.
4. It will install all updated node modules as well as missing platform (android/ios) folders inside project without disturbing the code already written.
5. **cd "ProjectName"** and then **cd ios** and then run **pod install**

**PS:** Take backup of your code in case it changes App.js

Comment: This doesn't work any more since 2021. You will get: `Cannot initialize new project because directory "project1" already exists.`

Answer (score 2):

in my case I didn't have the android folder at all, I used expo init to create my react native project

and to generate `Android Folder` run this command `expo prebuild`

Answer (score 1):

This is too late, but for anyone who is still having same issue and have a detached react native app, what i did for me I just run exp detach over my detached app and it created ios folder!

Answer (score 1):

Since react-native eject is depreciated in 60.3 and I was getting diff errors trying to upgrade form 60.1 to 60.3 regenerating the android folder was not working.

I had to

```
rm -R node_modules
```

Then update react-native in package.json to 59.1 (remove package-lock.json)

Run

```
npm install

react-native eject
```

This will regenerate your android and ios folders
Finally upgrade back to 60.3

```
react-native upgrade
```

react-native upgrade while back and 59.1 did not regenerate my android folder so the eject was necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I just found myself with this problem too, but I just solved it.

Surely when running the "react-native upgrade" command, it gave them the message that it was not necessary to update or with the command "react-native eject" that the command is not recognized.

`react-native upgrade`

Now you should use the `react-native upgrade --legacy true` command to back up your android folders or ios as the case may be as this command will replace your files.

`react-native upgrade --legacy true`

Now it's just telling you not to replace your package.json

Answer (score 1):

If you are lost with errors like **module not found** there is noway other the than following method if you have used react native CLI.I had faced similar issue as a result of openning xcode project from **.xcodeproj** file instead of **.xcworkspace**.
Also please note that react-native eject only for Expo project.

The only workaround to regenarate ios and android folders within a react native project is the following.

- Generate a project with same name using the command **react-native init**
- Backup your old project ios and android directories into a backup location
- Then copy ios and android directories from newly created project into your old not working project
- Run **pod install** within the copied ios directory

Now your problem should be solved

Answer (score 0):

i faced the same issue in react native .63 version. I tried above all methods but didn't worked. So, I tried like this deleted android/ios folders in my old project tree and initiated a new project with similar name in another folder, later copied android/ios folders from new project to old project and reset cache using react-native start --reset-cache and run react-native run-android and my attempt was successfull.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2020. React Native 0.63.3 no longer support this command `react-native eject`. Also `react-native upgrade` responsible for - ***Upgrade your app's template files to the specified or latest npm version using `rn-diff-purge` project.***

Available options can be found thought this command
`react-native --help`

Answer (score 0):

As of end of August 2021 and `react@17.0.2` / `react-native@0.65.1` none of presented solutions work for me. `expo-cli` cannot work with modern `react-native` downgrading `package.json` and messing up all dependencies to a state where I cannot use neither `react-native run-android` nor `expo run:android`.

I have reported this issue on project GitHub. Feel free to comment and support for some reasonable solution in this area:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/32109

Comment: It worked for me but new project should have a exact same name compared to failed project. After that you can copy android  / ios folders from new one to old one or copy old project app.js or other files to new one (works either way) but latter one is more successful. After copying remove lock files and run command yarn and then yarn start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

1.Delete `/ios /android`

2.Cretate file `app.json`

And add code:

```
{"name": "example", "displayName": "Example"}
```

3.run `npx react-native eject`

4.run `npx react-native run-android`

Answer (score 0):

1. npm i react-native-eject
2. npx react-native eject

(optional: to run ios App)

3. cd ios && pod install
4. npx react-native run-ios

Answer (score 0):

Run These command's from your project root:

```
npm i react-native-eject
npm i @react-native-community/cli
npx react-native eject
```

will generate the both android and ios folder

Comment: Like this code from 2021 says? https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430164/ Or is the `npx` significant enough to warrant a separate answer rather than editing?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, do this to regenerate android and ios folders

```
npm install --dev react-native-eject
npx react-native eject
```

finally pod install and run ios for iOS and run android for Android