# Reset android/ios project in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I reset Android/iOS project in React Native? Like in Ionic, we can use "ionic platform rm android" & then add it again, so it will add fresh project. How I can do same in React Native?

Comment: These links might help you. For Android:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214862/how-to-rebuild-the-entire-android-folder For ios:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project

Answer (score 4):

I had issues with Pod dependencies or Cocoapods in iOS.
Removing and de-integrating CocoaPods from my project fixed it.

```
gem install cocoapods-deintegrate
cd ios
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate

Answer (score 1):

Just remove folder `ios/build` for ios, and `android/build`. For android you may also need `cd ./android && ./gradlew clean` in some cases.

If you can create command inside `package.json` like
 "clear-android": "rm -rf android/build",
 "clear-ios": "rm -rf ios/build"

Answer (score 1):

To reset android build, delete cache and refresh you may need to do the following

If you have already generated signed keys and updated those in the gradles, you can build the production build, unless you can build the developer build (debugging apk)

1. Delete `build` inside `android/app` folder
2. Delete `build` inside `android` folder
3. run `rm -rf $HOME/.gradle/caches/` to delete cache
4. Open `build.gradle` -> `android/app/build.gradle`
5. comment out this line `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"`
6. Delete `index.android.bundle` file from `assets` folder `( android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle)`
7. run following command `react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res`
8. `react-native run-android --variant=release` (you have to generate signed keys and all the keys should updated in the gradle file ref (https://s-pace.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html)
9. if you dont have generate signed keys still you can run `react-native run-android`