# What should I do to apply changes for app if I make changes in AndroidManifest.xml?

Tags: android, react-native

I made some code changes in AndroidManifest.xml by adding some  tag and refactoring some code but when I run the app I do not see the changes. Do I need to rebuild android project?

Comment: Try wiping out cache by going to File->Invalidate Cache and Restart.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to rebuild the entire Android folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214862/how-to-rebuild-the-entire-android-folder)

Answer (score 4):

You have to re-install the app either with `android studio` or with `npx react-native run-android`

Whenever you make any change in the JS code you don't need to re-install the app but once any change made in the native code(Android, IOS), you have to re-install the app again either you are installing some native module or doing some change in the native side.