# How can I regenerate Android and IOS folders in React Native project version 0.61.x?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I tried to use

react-native upgrade

react-native upgrade --legacy true

react-native eject

no command is useful in this case

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I regenerate ios folder in React Native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project)

Comment: @FreakyCoder, no. As having the latest package, then running `react-native upgrade` would print out in the console `warn Specified version "0.61.5" is already installed in node_modules and it satisfies "0.61.5" semver range. No need to upgrade`. It does not seem to do anything.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you cant regenerate once you have built android and ios modules using react-native init myProjectName.you have to remove everything in the first and built one again