# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React-perflogger"

Tags: ios, react-native

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "React-perflogger":
In Podfile:
React-perflogger (from `../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger`)

Specs satisfying the `React-perflogger (from` ../node_modules/react-native/ReactCommon/reactperflogger`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: Have you manage to solved it?

Answer (score 5):

Edit your Podfile replacing `platform :ios, '10.0'` to `platform :ios, '11.0'`, then run `pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 2):

For me, running `npm install` in the root directory and then running `pod install` in the ios directory again, fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

After updating to `Expo` version `47` (from `44`), I've had indeed to change `platform :ios`, but from version '12.0'`to`platform :ios, '11.0'`, then` pod install --repo-update` indeed helped.

Basically, it's about updating the minimum `iOS` version to what's required by the requested podspecs. In the future, you might just try different values.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the IOS folder and used eject to regenerate (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52430164/9611924).
Afterwards `pod install` worked fine.