# Trying to put my first react-native sample app on an iOS device

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a small `react-native` sample app that I just wrote.
It is working as a web app, but now I want to test it as an iOS app.

To know how to do that I am looking at this document:
https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

The document starts like this:

```
1. Plug in your device via USB
    Connect your iOS device to your Mac using a USB to Lightning cable.
    Navigate to the ios folder in your project, then open the .xcodeproj file, .....
```

The problem is that my project has no *ios folder*.
What did I miss?

This is how I built the project in the terminal:

```
$ expo init MyApp
$ cd MyApp
$ npm install expo-av
$ npm run web
```

After that I wrote *App.js* and that's all. And it works as web app.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project - react-native upgrade should regenerate the ios and android folders for you.

Comment: Thanks but I never deleted any folder, so my problem was slightly different. I put the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, after running the command:

```
$ expo init MyApp
```

I was choosing the *blank template*.
But to have an *ios* folder the *minimal template* must be chosen.