# Is there any method in react native to generate android and ios folders again?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I messed up in my react-native android and ios folder while doing some changes in internal files, now project is not starting with lots of errors which is from gradle and pod file , can i clean this project to default stage or can i delete these folders and regenerate again for clean folders again in same project?.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I regenerate ios folder in React Native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project)

Answer (score 0):

When i messed-up my project i  just run "expo eject" again, but then you have to set-up your configuration again on android studio and x-code