# React native Android Folder Is Missing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, create-react-app

[See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJI3C.png) I am Unable to find the Android File in My react native Project folder.
i want to Turn my project in to the .APK but without the Android folder i am unable to do it.
would anyone help?

i have tried to Install the andoird sources in MY PROJECT by using
$ npm install react-native android

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project

Answer (score -1):

If you create Expo project then two way to run app on android and ios

#1
For using expo. your project directory, run `expo start`

#2
From your project directory, run `expo eject`
Now have a native project with ExpoKit!
now run `npx react-native run-android/ios`

Comment: could you please help me how to enject android and ios folder . i am newbie in this field. thanks in advance

Comment: Follow this link https://docs.expo.dev/expokit/eject/