# Posting different versions of your Android App in React-Native

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-gradle-plugin

I have a React-Native app in the Google Market. What I need to do is to create a separate version for our internal use (it will have some different functionality). Pretty much I need to have two apps in the market so I can have both of them on my phone. The closest answer that I found was [this](https://www.codementor.io/adamgold/react-native-running-dev-and-prod-apps-simultaneously-on-same-device-and-automating-the-builds-vqoazau7o). I forked my app and from my understanding, I need to change all the package names to a new one. However, the problem is in my app I use Google Services like FCM, I use some extra packagaes like sharing and importing posts. And those are also tied to a package name.

Are there any tutorials to doing this, or do I need to create a blank project and start building it up from scratch, adding packages?

Sorry, if I am unclear about the explanations. I thought this was a common practice, but did not find much information about it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change your apps name by cloning your repo and made some changes explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project/40741057#40741057).