# What is the significance of the appKey in AppRegistry.registerComponent(appKey, component)?

Tags: react-native

The declaration of [`AppRegistry.registerComponent`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appregistry.html#registercomponent) is as follows:

```
static registerComponent(appKey, componentProvider, section?)
```

The `appKey` variable is generated to be the same as the project name given in `react-native init projname`. But what is this value used for? If I change it to something else, the app throws an exception. How would I change this value to something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you call `AppRegistry.registerComponent` you're creating the bridge between javascript land and native land.

So if registering your component looks like this...

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('App', () => App);
```

Then your AppDelegate.m file will look something like this...

```
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                 moduleName:@"App"
                                                 initialProperties:nil
                                                 launchOptions:launchOptions];
```

The important part to note is this... `moduleName:@"App"`, where we're using the `appKey` and creating a RCTRootView mapped to the string "App" (e.g. your appKey)

These two strings should agree so that the RCTRootView knows how to map back to your app's javascript logic.

Comment: What is the `section?` for?

Answer (score -5):

Bit of a duplicate question: [Renaming a React Native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project)

Change the name in:

```
package.json
```

then run:

```
react-native upgrade
```

and change:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('projname', () => projname);
```

to:

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('newName', () => newName);
```

If changing the project name leaves the appKey value as the old project value then I would be surprised.

Comment: Okay. But what is this key used for other than making for additional steps in case you want to rename it?

Comment: Your app can have multiple components all connected to the same project.

Comment: AppRegistry.registerComponent(‘projname’, () => ComponentName);

Comment: As Chris Geirman commented you can have multiple RCTRootView in you own project.