# Can't find React native project on iOS Simulator or Xcode project

Tags: xcode, react-native, frontend, project

I have deleted my project on Xcode may it be `.xcworkspace` or `.xcodeproj`.

Because of that, I had to delete IOS and android folders while downgrading, updating and re-upgrading my react version to re-install IOS and android folders.

Thanks to that the emulator is working but unfortunately the project isn't present in the emulator and is still absent with Xcode. One thing to point out is that the simulator only appears when ran in the integrated terminal and nor in general terminal after cd-ing in the project folder.

Can anyone please help re-integrating the project in the emulator and on Xcode, please.

Here is the error when the emulator is running in a general terminal:

Here is the error when the emulator is running in a general terminal:

```
error Command failed: xcrun instruments -s
xcrun: error: Failed to determine realpath of '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.1.sdk' (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Here is the error for building the project within emulator when ran from VS code integrated terminal:

```
error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening project.xcodeproj
```

Comment: do you get any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

The process you need to follow is so similar to renaming a react native app. Basically you just need to run `react-native upgrade` in your root project directory. For further info you can check another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project). The instructions below explains how to create another react native project based on a copied one with a new name.

- First copy the directory which your to-be-name-changed application exists. And go to your newly cloned directory.
- Change the name at `index.ios/android.js` file which is given as a parameter to AppRegistry.
- Change the name and version accordingly on `package.json`
- Delete `/ios` and `/android` folders which are remaining from your older app.
- Run `$react-native upgrade` to generate `/ios` and `/android` folders again.
- Run `$react-native link` for any native dependency.
- Finally run `$react-native run-ios` or anything you want.

Courtesy of

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project
```

Comment: It's not in my trash I completely removed it by mistake. So I had to delete ios and android folder downgrade, update and re-upgrade my react version to re-install IOS and Android folder but my project still does not exist with Xcode and isn't present on the IOS simulator. I hope that helps if you have any specific questions please feel free asking

Comment: Do you have more simple steps?