# Renaming a React Native project

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a working react native app (without expo), running and compiling in both Android and iOS devices. Now I'm trying to rename the app, but I'm having problems with that.

Steps followed:

- I have deleted both ios and android directories.
- Changed the project name in my app.json
- Regenerated the android and ios directories with react-native upgrade --legacy (cause eject is not working anymore)
- Updated my podfile with the need
- Pod install

When i tried to compile my app via xcode, I got "null is not an object (evaluating '_RNGestureHandlerModule.default.Direction')

I guessed that was due to the autolinking when you install some react native third party components. So I deleted node_modules, and installed all react native navigation again. Then I ran react-native link. The previous error went away.

Now, I'm stuck with:

```
Target 'cjlrnneTests' has target dependency on Target 'cjlrnne'

That command depends on command in Target 'cjlrnne': script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”
```

Honestly, I don't know what else more to do / look for.

Can anyone please provide with some clue, or the steps to change a RN app's name?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

Comment: No i haven't, i'm trying to do it all by myself to understand the whole process

Comment: No worries, if you find yourself at a loose end, you could always take a look at the src code and look at what the scripts are doing.

Comment: Will try it later, thanks ;)

Comment: I think the safest way is to create another project with the new name and install dependencies again because you're dealing with complex batches for both iOS and Android

Comment: Honestly i thought it would be simple, thats why i tried to do it by myself

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming a React Native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32830046/renaming-a-react-native-project)

Comment: No. The "Renaming a React Native project" solution only talks about android.

Comment: finally did it with react-native-rename. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this package for renaming the app.
react-native-rename

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-rename

```
react-native-rename <newName>
```

It will automatically configure all the things.

Comment: As i said above, I was looking for a way to do it by my self, to exactly know what are the steps involved. Will try your solution later. Thanks